# How to work around Python 3 maximum string size?

Tags: python-3.x, out-of-memory, limit

On a 64 bit Python build with a `sys.maxsize` of 9223372036854775807 the
interpreter nevertheless throws a *MemoryError* if I allocate a string of more
than *INT_MAX - 512 MiB* chars:

```
$ python3
#Python 3.6.6 (default, Jul 19 2018, 14:25:17) 
[GCC 8.1.1 20180712 (Red Hat 8.1.1-5)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = "*" * 2684354560
>>> s = "*" * 2684354561
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

(The limit is the same for *bytes* whose element type is definitely 8 bits.)
There is plenty of free memory and swap so I am certain the system is not
hitting any physical limits.

What is happening here and how can I increase this cap?

Comment: Do you actually have a *use case* for a two-and-a-half-billion-character string? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo “Do you actually have a use case for a two-and-a-half-billion character syting?” – Data that size isn’t uncommon. In the case at hand though I’ve got some byzantine build system that fails on account of MemoryError for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution: turns out to be the
data segment size limit

```
$ ulimit -d
4194304
```

For some reason, these 4294967296 B translate to a 2684354560 B per-allocation
cap in Python.

Setting this value to *unlimited* removes the cap. This can be done externally
by the parent process (e. g. `ulimit -d unlimited` from the shell) or
in Python itself using the
[wrapper library for `resource.h`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html):

```
resource.setrlimit (resource.RLIMIT_DATA,
                    (resource.RLIM_INFINITY
                    ,resource.RLIM_INFINITY))
```

[Apparently](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) on more
recent kernels (4.7 and later) `RLIMIT_DATA` affects anonymous mappings too which
explains both the observed failure of large-ish allocations and my being
surprised.

Comment: @thierry-lathuille I added some info regarding the resource limit and why it was hit. It’s not Linux specific though, RLIMIT_DATA being POSIX.